# How to input bytes32[] on remix?

Tags: solidity, remix

I have a constructor like so:

```
constructor(bytes32[] proposalNames) public {
...
```

How do I input values for it on deplyoment with remix? I tried `["foo", "bar"]` but it said:

> creation of Ballot errored: Error encoding arguments: Error: invalid
> bytes32 value (arg="", coderType="bytes32", value="foo",
> version=4.0.47)

Comment: That's because `foo` and `bar` aren't `bytes32` arguments. Use something like: `["0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001","0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002"]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This:

```
const Web3 = require("web3");

console.log(Web3.utils.asciiToHex("foo"));
console.log(Web3.utils.asciiToHex("bar"));
```

Gives:

```
0x666f6f
0x626172
```

So I believe that one of the following should work for you:

```
[0x666f6f, 0x626172]
["0x666f6f", "0x626172"]
[0x666f6f0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, 0x6261720000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000]
["0x666f6f0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", "0x6261720000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"]
```

Comment: Thanks - interestingly only the last one worked.