# Error on Remix: creation of Ballot errored: Error encoding arguments: Error: expected array value

Tags: remix, contract-deployment, error

I'm a complete beginner and I'm trying to deploy the 3_Ballot.sol contract which is a sample contract on Remix. It compiles perfectly fine but it gives this error when I try to deploy it:

> creation of Ballot errored: Error encoding arguments: Error: expected
> array value (argument=null value="" code=INVALID_ARGUMENT
> version=abi/5.5.0)

There are lots of similar threads with the same error but I couldn't find which part I'm supposed to change in the code. Here's the sample ballot code I'm trying to deploy:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

/** 
 * @title Ballot
 * @dev Implements voting process along with vote delegation
 */
contract Ballot {
   
    struct Voter {
        uint weight; // weight is accumulated by delegation
        bool voted;  // if true, that person already voted
        address delegate; // person delegated to
        uint vote;   // index of the voted proposal
    }

    struct Proposal {
        // If you can limit the length to a certain number of bytes, 
        // always use one of bytes1 to bytes32 because they are much cheaper
        bytes32 name;   // short name (up to 32 bytes)
        uint voteCount; // number of accumulated votes
    }

    address public chairperson;

    mapping(address => Voter) public voters;

    Proposal[] public proposals;

    /** 
     * @dev Create a new ballot to choose one of 'proposalNames'.
     * @param proposalNames names of proposals
     */
    constructor(bytes32[] memory proposalNames) {
        chairperson = msg.sender;
        voters[chairperson].weight = 1;

        for (uint i = 0; i < proposalNames.length; i++) {
            // 'Proposal({...})' creates a temporary
            // Proposal object and 'proposals.push(...)'
            // appends it to the end of 'proposals'.
            proposals.push(Proposal({
                name: proposalNames[i],
                voteCount: 0
            }));
        }
    }
    
    /** 
     * @dev Give 'voter' the right to vote on this ballot. May only be called by 'chairperson'.
     * @param voter address of voter
     */
    function giveRightToVote(address voter) public {
        require(
            msg.sender == chairperson,
            "Only chairperson can give right to vote."
        );
        require(
            !voters[voter].voted,
            "The voter already voted."
        );
        require(voters[voter].weight == 0);
        voters[voter].weight = 1;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Delegate your vote to the voter 'to'.
     * @param to address to which vote is delegated
     */
    function delegate(address to) public {
        Voter storage sender = voters[msg.sender];
        require(!sender.voted, "You already voted.");
        require(to != msg.sender, "Self-delegation is disallowed.");

        while (voters[to].delegate != address(0)) {
            to = voters[to].delegate;

            // We found a loop in the delegation, not allowed.
            require(to != msg.sender, "Found loop in delegation.");
        }
        sender.voted = true;
        sender.delegate = to;
        Voter storage delegate_ = voters[to];
        if (delegate_.voted) {
            // If the delegate already voted,
            // directly add to the number of votes
            proposals[delegate_.vote].voteCount += sender.weight;
        } else {
            // If the delegate did not vote yet,
            // add to her weight.
            delegate_.weight += sender.weight;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @dev Give your vote (including votes delegated to you) to proposal 'proposals[proposal].name'.
     * @param proposal index of proposal in the proposals array
     */
    function vote(uint proposal) public {
        Voter storage sender = voters[msg.sender];
        require(sender.weight != 0, "Has no right to vote");
        require(!sender.voted, "Already voted.");
        sender.voted = true;
        sender.vote = proposal;

        // If 'proposal' is out of the range of the array,
        // this will throw automatically and revert all
        // changes.
        proposals[proposal].voteCount += sender.weight;
    }

    /** 
     * @dev Computes the winning proposal taking all previous votes into account.
     * @return winningProposal_ index of winning proposal in the proposals array
     */
    function winningProposal() public view
            returns (uint winningProposal_)
    {
        uint winningVoteCount = 0;
        for (uint p = 0; p < proposals.length; p++) {
            if (proposals[p].voteCount > winningVoteCount) {
                winningVoteCount = proposals[p].voteCount;
                winningProposal_ = p;
            }
        }
    }

    /** 
     * @dev Calls winningProposal() function to get the index of the winner contained in the proposals array and then
     * @return winnerName_ the name of the winner
     */
    function winnerName() public view
            returns (bytes32 winnerName_)
    {
        winnerName_ = proposals[winningProposal()].name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error message, it seems you are not providing any arguments to the constructor which expects a byte32 array "proposalNames".

Try giving the following sample arguments to the constructor and it should work.

["0x666f6f0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","0x6261720000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"]

[image]

Comment: It worked, thank you very much! I also tried to slightly change the sample arguments  you've provided and it also worked. So I was wondering, is it simply a necessity to always provide a random argument before deploying whenever an argument had not already been initially provided in our code? This would also be super helpful for me to learn, as it looks like a very simple trick that I somehow should've known but I don't :) Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah the constructor is a function that automatically executes at the time of deployment. In most cases it's responsible for initializing attributes inside the contract. In this case it initializes the attribute "proposalNames". The example that I gave you adds 2 names "foo" and "bar" to proposalNames. 

Since the constructor expects a byte32 array, you have to convert the string "foo" and "bar" to byte32. 

Refer this thread on how to do a conversion from string to byte32 - https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/89533/how-to-input-bytes32-on-remix

Answer (score 1):

For who has mssql at hand this was useful for me:

select cast('foo' as binary(32))

Result:

0x666F6F0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Use like this:

["0x666F6F0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).